# using xml .nodes() functionality to return all instances

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, nodes, cross-apply

I have the following code but it only returns the first instance of the `MonthDate` and `'Value'` values. I have been experimenting with the `.nodes()` and `Cross Apply` but can't figure out the syntax, I keep getting the error of;

> Invalid object name 'xmlContent.nodes'.

Code:

```
Declare @ngTest Table(ID int Identity, XmlContent XML)
Insert into @ngTest(XMLContent)(SELECT TOP 1 Cast(Cast(Data as ntext) as XML) FROM [Accounts].[dbo].[GoalChartData]  where goalID = 3661 and typeID = 2)

SELECT Top 1000 ID, 
    [XmlContent].value('(GoalMonteCarloChartResult/MonthlyMedianResults/MonthlyAmount/MonthDate/node())[1]', 'datetime') as MonthDate,
    [XmlContent].value('(GoalMonteCarloChartResult/MonthlyMedianResults/MonthlyAmount/Value/node())[1]','float') as Value
    from @ngTest CROSS APPLY [xmlContent].nodes('/MonthlyMedianResults/MonthlyAmount')
```

When I remove the `CROSS APPLY` conditional it returns the first instance of the `MonthDate` and `value`, but I want them all.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you need something like this:

```
SELECT Top 1000 
    ID, 
    MonthDate = XCol.value('(MonthDate)[1]', 'DATETIME'),
    [Value] = XCol.value('(Value)[1]', 'FLOAT') 
FROM
    @ngTest 
CROSS APPLY 
    [xmlContent].nodes('/MonthlyMedianResults/MonthlyAmount') AS XTbl(XCol)
```

The `.nodes()` call creates a "virtual" table (`XTbl`) with a single XML column (`XCol`), where each row represents the XML fragment of each `<MonthlyAmount>` node (and you must include a `AS table-alias(column-alias)` to your `CROSS APPLY` section so you can refer to this virtual table in your query).

You need to apply the XQuery `.value()` to **that virtual table** to fetch the values from this virtual table or XML fragments.

Comment: thank you for your quick suggestion, unfortunately i don't get any results from that above code.  I've verified that @ngTest gets populated with the 'XMLContent' xml but my results return empty with no errors. Am I supposed to be referencing XTbl anywhere?